# Convert Integer quint8 to qint16 in C++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, types, int

I have an integer dataytype quint8 (unsigned 8 bit, values 0...255) and i want to convert it to a integer datatype qint16 (signed 16 bit values −32.768...32.767). Can you tell me how to this in QT C++ in a ressource efficient way?

```
At the moment i am doing this but it doesn't work:

qint16 Audio::to16bitSample(quint8 sample8bit) {
qint16 sample16bit;
sample16bit = (sample8bit - 128) << 15;
return sample16bit;
qDebug("stop");
```

}

to idea is to expand the data from the 8 bit integer to the 16bit integer range -> so for example 8 bit unsigned +255 will be converted to 16 bit signed +32767 or  8 bit unsigned 0 will be converted to 16 bit signed -32768.

How to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Isn't it just a typedef? What is there to convert? What's wrong with using it as is?

Comment: What doesn't work? (Your `qDebug` statement won't execute btw.)

Comment: `to16bitSample(5);` returns `-32768`. What are you trying to achieve? Btw, `operator <<` to negative values is UB.

Comment: You're still unclear but I get the sense you want `to16bitSample(0)` to return a value of `-32768` and `to16bitSample(255)` must return a value of `32767`. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: (s16)((u8<<8)+u8-32768)

Comment: @RobbieE yes that is what i want to do ;)

Comment: It'll be cast implicitly. No need to worry here

Answer (score 0):

I made it this code works:

```
qint16 Audio::to16bitSample(quint8 sample8bit) {

qint16 sample16bit;

sample16bit = (sample8bit - 128) * 256;

return sample16bit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The closest integer solution to what you want is this:

```
qint16 to16bitSampleMy(quint8 sample8bit)
{
    return ((sample8bit) << 8) - 32768;
}
```

Test:

```
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(0);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(5);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(127);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(128);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(129);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(200);
qDebug() << to16bitSampleMy(255);
```

Output:

```
-32768 
-31488 
-256 
0 
256 
18432 
32512
```

You did write, that you want `0 -> -32768` and `255 -> 32767`, but in this case the difference between nearest point won't be integer. If you still need this, all you need to do is to solve [a simple equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form).

Comment: that's why I wrote one more `+u8` than you did

Comment: @user3528438 indeed, your variant is better.